# C++ bit field with fragmented fields and uint alias

Tags: c++

I'm trying to represent a 32-bit ARM register, CPSR, cleanly in C++.

It looks like this:

```
|31|30|29|28|27| 26 25 |24|23..20| 19..16| 15..10|9|8|7|6|5|  4..0|
| N| Z| C| V| Q|IT[1:0]| J| Resvd|GE[3:0]|IT[7:2]|E|A|I|F|T|M[4:0]|
```

I want to be able to access this register's fields, while also being able to treat it like a 32 bit word.

For example, "CPSR.M" would be just the M field, readable and writable, and so on.  Also, "CPSR" by itself would present the register as a uint32_t .

I think I might get at least part-way there using unions and bit fields:  e.g:

```
typedef struct {
    uint32_t M               : 5;
    uint32_t T               : 1;
    uint32_t F               : 1;
    uint32_t I               : 1;
    uint32_t A               : 1;
    uint32_t E               : 1;
    uint32_t IT1             : 6;
    uint32_t GE              : 4;
    uint32_t ReservedRAZSBZP : 1;
    uint32_t J               : 1;
    uint32_t IT0             : 2;
    uint32_t Q               : 1;
    uint32_t V               : 1;
    uint32_t C               : 1;
    uint32_t Z               : 1;
    uint32_t N               : 1;
} CPSRType;
```

My problem is that I'm not sure how to dereference CPSR.IT when it is split into two pieces like that.  Also,  how might I have CPSR.IT, CPSR.M,  and (uint32_t)CPSR  all be valid L-Values?

Are bitfields and unions the way, or do I need to try something else?

Thanks.

Comment: There's no `union` in your question

Comment: what about using a indexer (operator[])?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, it is not very clear if you want to directly access the CPSR memory-mapped register, or if you want to get/set different fields after reading from this register or before writing into this register.

**Here is what you can do on a local copy `CPSRType CPSR` of this register:**

You can get the `IT` value as follows:

```
uint8_t value = (CPSR.IT1<<2) | CPSR.IT0;
```

You can set the `IT` value as follows:

```
CPSR.IT0 = value & 0x03;
CPSR.IT1 = (value>>2) & 0x3F;
```

You can set the `M` value as follows:

```
CPSR.M = value & 0x1F;
```

You can set the entire structure as follows:

```
CPSR = *(CPSRType*)&value; // where 'value' must be a 32-bit variable
```

**Of course, you will eventually need to read / write the memory-mapped register itself:**

```
CPSR = *(CPSRType*)REG_ADDRESS; // Read register
*(CPSRType*)REG_ADDRESS = CPSR; // Write register
```

Comment: I was hoping I could just do something like CPSR.IT=0xA5, since I am porting pseudocode that does operations like this, but there aren't too many occurrences, so the bitwise ops approach will be OK. Thank you.